# How to set the expandUriTemplateVariables of class RedirectView to false, which is by default true

Tags: java, spring

How to set the variable `expandUriTemplateVariables` of class `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView` to `false`, which is by default `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView(url);
    rv.setExpandUriTemplateVariables(false);
    return new ModelAndView(rv);
```